# Does a visual studio setup project allow selective application installs?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment

The software that I am delivering is a suite of multiple programs including different types of clients and different types of servers. Multiple servers can coexist on the same machine or be distributed over the network and this is also true of the clients. The actual topology of the suite is dependent on the users need.

What I want to do is package all of the necessary executables and programs into one single installer that a user can select components out of. Something like a standard Microsoft office install where one could pick different components to include or exclude. I also want to be able to show specific screens during install that are dependent on which products were selected for install (e.g. if the desktop client is installed, a screen prompting for the location of the authentication server is shown, but this screen is not shown if the desktop client is not selected for install).

Are these things possible with the Visual Studio Setup Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Visual Studio setup project has always been very basic. Microsoft announced that 2010 would be the last Visual Studio version containing it and in 2012 it's gone.

In 2012 you have the free version of InstallShield, but it won't do the job for you either. There are paying version that should do the job but general opinion seems to be quite negative about them.

Basically you should bite the bullet and learn WiX. The doc is not organized in a way that makes it easy to learn but you'll get there.